# Using CSS selector for find element with multiple class in Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I want to find element below with find_elements_by_css_selector(**...**) but it have multiple class `artdeco-modal`, `artdeco-modal--layer-default` ,`ip-fuse-limit-alert`.
I used Selenium IDE for collecting x-path, css selector but it's not doing well. So how can I do it using mannually? What is the exact css selector for this element?

`<div data-test-modal="" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="artdeco-modal artdeco-modal--layer-default ip-fuse-limit-alert" size="small" aria-labelledby="ip-fuse-limit-alert__header">`

Answer (score 0):

Use any of the css selector. either `classname` or `tagname[attributename='attributevalue']`

```
div.artdeco-modal.artdeco-modal--layer-default.ip-fuse-limit-alert
```

OR

```
div[aria-labelledby='ip-fuse-limit-alert__header']
```

---

Use multiple attribute as well

```
div.artdeco-modal.artdeco-modal--layer-default.ip-fuse-limit-alert[aria-labelledby='ip-fuse-limit-alert__header']
```

---

You can use following `xpath` as well to identify the element.

```
//div[@class='artdeco-modal artdeco-modal--layer-default ip-fuse-limit-alert']
```

Or

```
//div[@aria-labelledby='ip-fuse-limit-alert__header']
```